# I am facing Issue in updating my adt to version 23

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

When i am updating my adt to 23 its showing some error

[image]

and following is the error details

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
```

session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature,23.0.6.1720515
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature,23.0.6.1720515

and have delete my previous eclipse and download a fresh but i am facing the same prob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Developer Tools Update Site url changed:

- https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (old)
- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (new)

so change it in eclipse, go to Help > Install New Software.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that eclipse has edited or deleted files when updating

follow steps for updating eclipse

```
 1. Download Eclipse from the official site
 2. Download and install JDK latest version
 3. After installing the eclipse, go to Help > Install New Software.
 4. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
 5. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the
Name and the following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Click OK.
 6. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
 7. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
 8. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
 9. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```